# Create insert function (postgresql) in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, insert, sql-insert

I am trying to create a dynamic function to insert value in a postgresql database, in node.js. Instead of typing the queries by itself, I want to type the function and argument and it will execute the query when I call it.

I want to recreate this:

```
var query = "INSERT INTO my_table (id, fname) VALUES (3, 'Karees')"
```

I'm sure there is a correct syntax for this but I don't know what it is. So I tried to do it like in System.out.print in java. It is saying my table is undefined by if I just replace it in the query there is no problem. My problem I guess is the variable referencing.

My code:

```
function run(){
function insert(table, pkey, field, value){
    var query = "INSERT INTO "+ table +" ("+ pkey +", "+ field +") VALUES ('"+ value +"')"
    client.query(query, (err, res) => {
  console.log(err, res)
  client.end()
})
}
insert(my_table, 3, fname, Karees)
}
```

Result:

```
connected successfully
(node:1926828) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: my_table is not defined
    at run (C:\Users\Johnathan Aggrey\Documents\Job\IBVAZE TECH\Spark\conn.js:27:8)
    at client.connect.then.catch.finally (C:\Users\Johnathan Aggrey\Documents\Job\IBVAZE TECH\Spark\conn.js:12:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:1926828) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1926828) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: "my_table is not defined"

Comment: Is `my_table` a variable or did you mean to pass the string `"my_table"` into the function? Also, you generally don't want to form queries by concatenating variables, especially if the data is coming from somewhere else. This opens you up to SQL injection attacks. Look into how to parameterized queries.

Comment: It's not a string, it's my table name in the database

Comment: Then it should be a string.

Comment: I changed it as a string, now it is saying { error: syntax error at or near "3"

Comment: It would be helpful if you also listed what you expect the query string to look like.

Comment: var query = "INSERT INTO my_table (id, fname) VALUES (3, 'Karees')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several values that should be strings in this line:

```
insert(my_table, 3, fname, Karees)
```

Assuming `my_table` is the name of your table, and `fname` and `Karees` are also values (and not variables) that you want in your query string, you need to write it like this:

```
insert('my_table', 3, 'fname', 'Karees')
```

Comment: I did this, now it is saying
connected successfully
{ error: syntax error at or near "3"